# Unable to Extract the Specific cell value against the lowest Priced item in a excel column and paste it to different worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, powershell, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to extract from an excel file(named as book1.xls) the lowest **Price** present under the 'Price' column of the sheet1 and want to copy it along with it's respective value which is present in the same sheet1 but under the 'Departure City' excel column (i.e the departure time), to a different book2.xls file .

[data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLcrk.jpg)

I want to paste the above two data into a predefined cell locationi.e Departure Time@ C13 cell and Lowest Price@ E13 cell.

[Output File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR2XE.jpg)

Am currently using formula in th eoutput file to extract :-

`=INDEX(range,MATCH(MIN([book1.xls]Sheet1!X2:X80),X2:X80,0))`

But only able to get `#NAME?` as output.

Not sure if its correct approach. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a `#NAME?` error when there is typo in your formula,

Is your named range your using as the `INDEX` array actually called `range`.
That looks like the only part of the formula the mistake could be lying with.

Try using the formula without using a named range, and it should work, then fix the named range and you can use that.

See more about the `#NAME?` error on the Microsoft site:

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/how-to-correct-a-name-error-b6d54e31-a743-4d7d-9b61-40002a7b4286

Answer (score -1):

**This will solve the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- First you have to get the **Departure Time** 
  for the **Lowest Price**.
- Formula in Cell `B155` when the **PriceTable** 
  Workbook is Open.

  `=INDEX(Deptime,MATCH(MIN([PriceTable.xlsm]Sheet1!$H$2:$H$7),[PriceTable.xlsm]Sheet1!$H$2:$H$7,0))`
- Formula in Cell `B155` when the **PriceTable**
  Workbook is Closed.

  `=INDEX(Deptime,MATCH(MIN('C:\Users\User\Desktop\[PriceTable.xlsm]Sheet1'!$H$2:$H$7),'C:\Users\User\Desktop\[PriceTable.xlsm]Sheet1'!$H$2:$H$7,0))`

**N.B.**

- **Deptime**, is Named Range given to 
  `D145:D150` in Destination Sheet *(Where you 
   are getting Departure Time for the Lowest 
   Price).*
- You may replace `Deptime` with `D145:D150`.
- File path when PriceTable workbook is closed 
  may vary.

---

- Formula in Cell `D155` to get the **Lowest 
  Price.**

`=INDEX(H145:H150,MATCH(B155,D145:D150,0))`

- *Remember this process will work properly when 
  both Workbook (Destination & PriceTable) has 
  same Data structure.*

**You may adjust Workbook & Cell references as your need.**